# Node.js app: "Disk quota exceeded" when installing npm module with lots of files

Tags: swisscomdev

When adding https://www.npmjs.com/package/material-design-icons as a dependency to my Node application, `cf push` fails with `Disk quota exceeded` when running `npm install`. Since the complete application including `node_modules` has about 100 MB (way below the limit of 1 GB), I assume it might have to do with the fact that `material-design-icons` has about 86'000 files (for whatever reason).

Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Typical quota systems have both a block quota (the 1GB one) and an inode quota (based on number of files) -- necessary because most filesystems have creation-time limits on both of these resources. If none of the solutions given work for you, you may be hitting the latter.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is to ignore the node_modules directory using the .cfignore file (the same concept as the .gitignore file). The files described in the .cfignore aren't uploaded to Cloud Foundry when you push your app.
You can find more about .cfignore here: https://docs.developer.swisscom.com/apps/deploy-apps/prepare-to-deploy.html#exclude

The solution is to delete the directory node_modules from your app directory before to push it. The description of the needed modules must be in the file package.json under dependencies. I tested a simple express app adding the material-design-icons module. Pushing the application without the content of the directory node_modules works, since in staging the modules are downloaded and added to the application.

Comment: This is already the case. The issue happens when "npm install" runs on the server.

Comment: Did you try to see if the problem is present using different buildpacks? For example the latest buildpack is in github the version 1.5.4: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/nodejs-buildpack.git, If you don't specify any buildpack it will be used the builpack version 1.5.2 as shown by the command: "cf buildpacks".

Comment: You might need to delete and re-push your app though, since Cloud Foundry caches some files and the container might be filled with these cached files. If you delete and re-push the app, you're getting a clean container from scratch which might solve your problem.

Comment: Same problem with the newest buildpack (1.5.4). And same problem after deleting the app. But it doesn't really matter, an npm module of 86'000 files is probably not the smartest idea (as others have discovered: https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/issues/14).

Comment: Can you post the list of the modules you are using? I would like to reproduce the issue. Using the modules material-design-icons and express I was able to reproduce the issue and I solved with the .cfignore. Maybe it is possible to find a way to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to delete the directory node_modules from your app directory before to push it. The description of the needed modules must be in the file package.json under dependencies. I tested a simple express app adding the material-design-icons module. Pushing the application without the content of the directory node_modules works, since in staging the modules are downloaded and added to the application.

Comment: You may incorporate both your solutions into one answer. On Stack Overflow answer doesn't force to describe exactly one approach to the problem.

Comment: See comment below, the issue happens when "npm install" runs on the server. The difference might be that I have lots of additional dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

The solution with `.cfignore` should work. You might need to delete and re-push your app though, since Cloud Foundry caches some files and the container might be filled with these cached files. If you delete and re-push the app, you're getting a clean container from scratch which might solve your problem.

Comment: No luck, the problem persists.

Comment: I'm having a hard time trying to reproduce your error... Is your repo public? Are there some other folders or files you might `.cfignore` (e.g. docs, test, editor configs, linter configs...) to make the push as lightweight as possible? Do you have a `postinstall` or other script set in your `package.json` file which might get executed by Cloud Foundry during the staging phase?

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem. I solved it by doing the following:

- Using `.cfignore`
- Specifying the update `nodejs` in `package.json`
- Using the latest `buildpack`